# custom audio tag in fire fox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This just works in chrome and safari , and i tried to run it on fire fox and it does'nt work.
is there a codes that works on firefox?

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
```

Comment: You can't run tags with the `-webkit-` prefix on the firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371159/firefox-equivalent-of-moz-media-controls